# Can we automate Electron app with protractor?

Tags: testing, automation, protractor, electron

There is a application which is built on top of electron.js acts as desktop application, is automated using protractor due to slight changes Dev team is providing build to QA as .exe file.

So I want to use the existing scripts.

Please let me know if there is any possibility that Electron app can be integrated with protractor framework, if not suggest any other open source tool which can we used to automate Electron app other than Spectron.